# Некорректно заполняется массив байт при работе с несколькими потоками

Tags: java, многопоточность

Три потока ReadThread должны читать из файлов байты и выводить их на консоль. Вместо этого трижды выводится последовательность байтов только последнего файла. 
Почему?

```
    // 1.) создаем список потоков с именами файлов для чтения
    List <Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i<fileNames.size(); i++) {
        threads.add(new ReadThread(fileNames.get(i)));
    }
    // 2.) запускаем потоки
    for (Thread currentThread : threads) {
        currentThread.start();
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
}

public static class ReadThread extends Thread {
    private static String name;
    public ReadThread(String fileName) {
        this.name = fileName;
    }

    public synchronized void run() {
        maxDuplicateByte();
    }

    public synchronized static void maxDuplicateByte() {

        // заполняем массив байтами 
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
        try {
            InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(name);
            byteArray = new byte[fis.available()];
            fis.read(byteArray);
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // выводим массив на печать
        for (byte bt : byteArray) {
            System.out.print(bt + " ");
        }
```

Comment: а `fileName` везде разный?

Comment: Да, конечно. В шаге №1 потоки создаются с аргументами из списка fileNames, который до этого заполнялся вручную.

Comment: так у вас свойство name статическое - одно на все инстансы

Comment: блин, точно. убрал static и всё заработало.